# expect fails when running proc inside proc

Tags: bash, unix, tcl, expect

My script works fine (retrieves sftp prompt) when using one proc. But when I try to use proc inside proc, script gets stuck, and I do not know why.

Please do not refactor the code, that is not the point, I need to understand what is the issue here.

Working code:

```
proc sftp_connect {} {
  set times 0;
  set connection_retry 2
  set timeout 1;
  while { $times < $connection_retry } {
    spawn sftp ${SFTP_USER}@${SFTP_SERVER}
    expect {
      timeout { puts "Connection timeout"; exit 1}
      default {exit 2}
      "*assword:*" { 
        send "${SFTP_PASSWORD}\n";
        expect {
          "sftp>" { puts "Connected"; set times [ expr $times+1]; exp_continue}
        }
      }
    }
  }
  send "quit\r";
}

sftp_connect
```

Debug output:

```
expect: does "\r\nsftp> " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "sftp>"? yes
```

But after moving send password into separate proc, expect does not retrieve sftp prompt anymore ("sftp>"):

```
proc sftp_send_password {} {
  send "${SFTP_PASSWORD}\n";
  expect {
    "sftp>" { puts "Connected"; set times [ expr $times+1]; exp_continue}
  }
}

proc sftp_connect {} {
  set times 0;
  set connection_retry 2
  set timeout 1;
  while { $times < $connection_retry } {
    spawn sftp ${SFTP_USER}@${SFTP_SERVER}
    expect {
      timeout { puts "Connection timeout"; exit 1}
      default {exit 2}
      "*assword:*" { sftp_send_password }
    }
  }
  send "quit\r";
}

sftp_connect
```

Debug output:

```
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "sftp>"? yes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have my copy of "Exploring Expect" handy, but I think you're running into a variable scoping issue. `spawn` invisibly sets a variable named `spawn_id`. When you call spawn in a proc, that variable is scoped only for that proc. Declare it as global:

```tcl
proc sftp_connect {} {
  global spawn_id
  # ... rest is the same
}
```

I think you don't have to do the same thing in `sftp_send_password` because expect has a more forgiving scoping scheme than Tcl (if expect does not find a local variable, look in the global namespace).

Your `sftp_send_password` proc will not affect the `times` variable in `sftp_connect` though, due to the same variable scoping issue. I'd recommend

```tcl
proc sftp_send_password {times_var} {
  upvar 1 $times_var times     ;# link this var to that in the caller
  send "${SFTP_PASSWORD}\n";
  expect {
    "sftp>" { puts "Connected"; incr times; exp_continue} 
  }
  # note use of `incr` instead of `expr`
}
```

And then the `sftp_connect` proc sends the `times` variable **name**:

```
sftp_send_password times
```

Comment: but how does it affect waiting for the prompt?

Comment: The `send` and `expect` commands need the `$spawn_id` variable to know what process to talk to, so it's vital that `spawn` creates that variable in the correct namespace.

Answer (score 3):

The following is from the `expect`'s [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expect.1.html):

> Expect takes a rather liberal view of scoping.  In particular, variables read by commands specific to the Expect program will be sought  first  from
> the  local scope, and if not found, in the global scope.  For example, this obviates the need to place `global timeout` in every procedure you write
> that uses expect.  On the other hand, variables written are always in the local scope (unless a `global` command has been issued).  **The most  common
> problem this causes is when `spawn` is executed in a procedure.**  Outside the procedure, `spawn_id` no longer exists, so the spawned process is no longer
> accessible simply because of scoping.  Add a `global spawn_id` to such a procedure.